# Integral very short math question please?

Tags: integration

So I had to find the integral of 
$$
\frac{\cos x}{6-5\sin x+(\sin x)^2}
$$
...And I found it..it is $2\arctan(5-2\sin x)$...how can I bring this in terms of logarithms?

Comment: Logarithms? Why, how, what for....do you want logarithms here? In what way?

Comment: well the solution in my book is log(3-sinx-log(2-sinx))..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you wrote, but that doesn't seem to be the solution, either.

Comment: The corrected comment: Under change of variable $y = \sin(x)$, $\int \frac{\cos x}{6-5\sin x+(\sin x)^2} dx = \int \frac{dy}{6 - 5y + y^2}$. Since $\frac{1}{6 - 5y + y^2} = \frac{1}{y-3} - \frac{1}{y-2}$...

Comment: I don't know if your mistake happened at completing the square or something that later followed.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int\frac{\cos x}{\sin^2x-5\sin x+6}dx=\int\frac{\cos x}{(\sin x-3)(\sin x-2)}dx=:I$$

Substitution:

$$u=\sin x\Longrightarrow du=dx\cos x\Longrightarrow$$

$$I=\int\frac{du}{(u-3)(u-2)}=\int\left(\frac{1}{u-3}-\frac{1}{u-2}\right)du=$$

$$=\log\frac{u-3}{u-2}+C=\log\frac{\sin x-3}{\sin x-2}+C$$

I don't understand where did you get that $\,arctan\,$ from...

Comment: The OP probably conpleted the square instead of decomposing into partial fractions. But I'm afraid he/she made a mistake doing so.

Comment: @user60127: The summation of coefficients of terms in the denominator is zero. Indeed, $1+(-5)+6=0$ so one solution is $6$ and the other is $-1$. +1

Comment: Your factorization is off.

Comment: "Off" is a gentle term: it was wrong, period. I've edited the answer, thanks @Mike

Answer (score 2):

Do a u-sub; $u = \sin(x)$, $du = \cos(x)\,dx$ to get
$$ \int{cos(x)\, dx\over 6 - 5\sin(x) + \sin^2(x)} = 
\int{du\over6 - 5u + u^2}$$
The integral will yield to partial fractions.